# Create an array for an each object present in an array using for loop in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I been searching for this but failed to find a proper solution. Is it possible to create an array for each object present in an array?Lets say I have an array 'fruits'

```
   NSMutableArray *fruits=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [fruits addObject:@"apple"];
   [fruits addObject:@"banana"];
   [fruits addObject:@"mango"];
```

Now there are three objects in my array. IS it possible to create an array for each of the object present in the array 'fruit'.

Can I do something like

```
   for(int i=0;i<fruits.count;i++){
    NSMutableArray *fruits_%d=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
```

I know it is a blunder. Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with these arrays? Most likely you want to create an array of these new arrays.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for a NSDictionary - you could store  arrays with the fruit names as the keys

Comment: Lets say, I have an array called account and then I would like to store all the details of those accounts in another array created. @rmaddy

Comment: (But you can't do this: `NSMutableArray *fruits_%d=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`.  If you want multiple `fruits` arrays, make it an array of arrays.)

Comment: I know it is a blunder. I used that just to give a clear understanding about my question.  @HotLicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *fruitDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[fruitDict setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] forKey:@"apple"];
[fruitDict setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] forKey:@"banana"];
[fruitDict setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] forKey:@"mango"];
```

Or a little cleaner syntax:

```
NSMutableArray *fruits=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[fruits addObject:@"apple"];
[fruits addObject:@"banana"];
[fruits addObject:@"mango"];

NSMutableDictionary *fruitDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *fruit in fruits)
{
    [fruitDict setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] forKey:fruit];
}
```

Then when you want to retrieve the array:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = fruitDict[@"banana"]
```

The above code will yield the array for the banana item.

Comment: Instead of forKey:@"apple", Can I use forKey:[fruits objectatindex:0]; ?

Comment: @T_77 No, that would create a dictionary with only one key, `@"apple"`. You *could* use your `for(int i=0;i<fruits.count;i++)` and `forKey:[fruits objectAtIndex:i]` though.

Comment: ya...thats what I am thinking. Let me check!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want but maybe you can do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *fruits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[fruits addObject:@"apple"];
[fruits addObject:@"banana"];
[fruits addObject:@"mango"]; 

NSMutableArray *arrayOfFruits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:fruits.count];
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.count; i++) {
    [arrayOfFruits addObject:@[fruits[i]]];
}
```